# PHP - cURL error 58 - Problem with the local SSL certificate

Tags: php, curl

So I am working on a credit card integration project where they needs certificates.
This is my PHP variable that uses the key and the pem

```
$certificate = array('private_key_path' => '/usr/www/users/2619100.key', 'public_key_path' => '/usr/www/users/2619100.pem', 'password' => '4545xss');
```

When I ran the whole code it throws an error

cURL error 58 - Problem with the local SSL certificate

Not sure it doesn't describe the actual error, does anyone have any idea. Here is the PHP code

```
    $params = array('device_fingerprint' => array('ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $api_key, 'Content-Type: application/json', 'gateway-entity-id: ' . $this->gateway_entity_id, 'client-request-id: ' . uniqid()));  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params)); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    if($this->request_type == 'VALIDATION' || $this->request_type == 'PRODUCTION') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $this->certificate['private_key_path']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->certificate['public_key_path']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $this->certificate['password']);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    //print_r($data); exit;
    if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
        $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
        throw new Exception('cURL error ' . $errno . ' - ' . $error_message);
    }
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Temporarily use the `-k` option also known as `--insecure` for testing

Comment: @barrycarter Its already there if you check these lines please

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: My bad, sorry. Try running curl from the command line with the same parameters?

Comment: @barrycarter It's a shared server so the hosting won't allow the command line option, unfortunately. Is there a way to get an exact error description, just a problem with local SSL is not helping (:

Comment: I notice you've set the verbose option-- is there anywhere you print it? As a last ditch effort, you can try looking at the headers, but I sense curl is unhappy about something else (like ca-certificates or something)

Comment: Are you using a public key or a cert ? It's not the same thing